# Problem in session -- codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am checking session like this

```
if($this->session->userdata('username') == "")

            $this->checkusername();

function checkusername()

    {

        if($this->session->userdata('username') == "") {
                redirect('admin');


    }
```

In firefox after correct login also,it redirects to login page ??
i am using codeignitor session..

Comment: The code provided is not your problem, whatever the code above is meant to achieve.

Comment: Agree with @Ross. Please, check that `$this->session->userdata('username')` is returning a good value. Check [this link](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) for more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have intentionally set `$this->session->userdata('username')` to an empty string, your test will always be false.

I am assuming by checking if your session variable is set to `""` you are trying to check if it hasn't been set.

In Codeigniter

```
$this->session->userdata('username')
```

Will return boolean `false` if `'username'` has not been set as a session variable

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind however, that when session is based on CI cookies it can be hacked from client side to pose as every username they choose